# Difference between sort(), rank(), and order()

Tags: r, sorting, difference, ranking

What is the **difference between sort(), rank(), and order() in R**.

Can you explain with examples?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`sort()` sorts the vector in an ascending order.

`rank()` gives the respective rank of the numbers present in the vector, the smallest number receiving the rank 1.

`order()` returns the indices of the vector in a sorted order.

for example: if we apply these functions are applied to the vector - *c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4)*

`sort(c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4))` will give c(1,2,3,4,5)

`rank(c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4))` will give c(3,1,2,5,4)

`order(c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4))` will give c(2,3,1,5,4).
if you put these indices in this order, you will get the sorted vector. Notice how v[2] = 1, v[3] = 2, v[1] = 3, v[5] = 4 and v[4] = 5

also there is a **tie** handling method in **R**. If you run `rank(c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2))` it will give Rank 1 to 1, since there are two 2 present R will rank them on 2 and 3 but assign Rank 2.5 to each of them, next 3 will get Rank 4.0, so

`rank(c (3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2))` will give you output *[4.0 1.0 2.5 6.0 5.0 2.5]*

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Also worth mentioning how `rank` handles ties. Check for example `rank(c(3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2))`

Comment: If order is confusing, think of it in context of sorting a vector using index notation: `c(3, 1, 2, 5, 4)[order(c(3, 1, 2, 5, 4))]`