# order() function gives wrong order for characters in R

Tags: r

```
xx = c("calculated_p3", "calculated_c1" ,"calculated_p2" ,"calculated_c2", "calculated_d2",
"calculated_d3", "calculated_c3", "calculated_p1" ,"calculated_d1")

order(xx)
```

The output is: 2 4 7 9 5 6 8 3 1

Why is the "calculated_d1" ordered as the first element? And why is "calculated_c2" ordered as the 9th element? I don't understand here. Shouldn't "calculated_c1" be the first one?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, index #2 is the first ordered element and that is the original "_c1". Do: `xx[order(xx)]` and you'll get them ordered correctly

Comment: This might be helpful to understand the functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017285/difference-between-sort-rank-and-order-in-r . Maybe you just need `sort(xx)`

Answer (score 2):

`order` is written such that `xx[order(xx)]` is the same as `sort(xx)`.

The numbers don't refer to the position that each entry should go to but rather the position the entries should come from if they were in order.

`calculated_c1` should indeed be the first one. As it is in position 2, the first number is therefore a 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your order you can use factors:

```
factor(xx, xx)
[1] calculated_p3 calculated_c1 calculated_p2 calculated_c2 calculated_d2 calculated_d3 calculated_c3 calculated_p1
[9] calculated_d1
9 Levels: calculated_p3 calculated_c1 calculated_p2 calculated_c2 calculated_d2 calculated_d3 ... calculated_d1
```